# mod_rewrite does not work when $_POST['content'] contains "from"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I am working on a custom php CMS system which has a directory called @admin as the admin dashboard.

eg. http://localhost/@admin

I am trying to add a blog post and posting to:
http://localhost/@admin/blog/create

Which also is the same URL when filling out the initial form to post to.

I have 2 .htaccess setup 1 in @admin directory and 1 in the root public_html directory.. I have mod_rewrite setup in both htaccess files with following lines:

```
@admin dir

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /@admin
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z-]+)([/]?)$ @modules/index.php?module=$1&action=$2  [QSA,L]

root public_html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^@]+)$ index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Now this is all working correctly for the most part however I am trying to post a new entry to the post which is about 4 paragraphs and when I do try to post it apache seems to be pushing me into the root public_html .htaccess and using index.php to handle the request which does not know any of the admin panel modules.

However if I change a word "from" to "frum" in the last paragraph of:

> OIART is a place where only a select few get to spend every minute together living and breathing a common passion known as the music industry. If I'm on the road touring, in the studio, or at the office uploading music to distribution partners, every day I use fundamentals learned from my instructors and peers at the school. What I studied there, along with the confidence and courage to stand out and network towards a career was the base foundation that allowed me to have the experiences I have today.

in the blog post all works again and it is properly redirected to the index.php in the @modules folder.

I am totally lost at this and hoping someone with more mod_rewrite knowledge could give some insights.

Thanks!

Comment: mod_rewrite applies rules in file-system order. a rewrite applied at (say) `/home/sites/example.com` will evaluate/execute before any rules that applies at `/home/sites/example.com/deeply/nested/sub/directory`. You would need to add execlusions to your root directory rules to exempt the subdir's urls from being evaluated by the root dir's rules.

Comment: Really? In every practical case I've found it was the opposite. In fact, unless you use some sort of `Inherit` option, any rules in parent directories get completely ignored.

Comment: Note: my comment only applies to mod_rewrite rules, not htaccess directives in general. In general, directives work the way @MarcB describes.

Comment: I even tried: RewriteRule ^@admin/([a-z]+)/([a-z-]+)([/]?)$ @admin/@modules/index.php?module=$1&action=$2  [QSA,L] within the root .htaccess without any luck :(

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something else that's redirecting you to index.php? This doesn't look like it's related to mod_rewrite at all.